# git fast-import for existing files in the repository

Tags: git

I have local git repository and a large number of files (~4 million, total size ~700GB) that I want to check into git. Using git filters, I want to track not the files' real contents but only some reference to the file (similar to what `git lfs` is doing). Adding and committing the files (in chunks) still takes a very long time and I'm hoping to reduce that time by using `git fast-import`.

I can't figure out, though, how to exactly replicate `git add <file> && git commit -m <message>` using `git fast-import`. Let's consider the following situation:

```sh
mkdir /tmp/git_fast_test && cd /tmp/git_fast_test
git init
echo "1234" > testfile
```

Now I run the following python script, which commits a file `testfile` with mode 644 and content `1234` to the git repo. This should now correspond *exactly* to `/tmp/git_fast_test/testfile`.

```py
import subprocess
import time

proc = subprocess.Popen(["git", "fast-import"], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, cwd="/tmp/git_fast_test")
proc.stdin.write(b"commit refs/heads/master\n")
proc.stdin.write(b"committer Me <me@me.org> %d +0100\n" % int(time.time()))

# commit message
proc.stdin.write(b"data 5\n")
proc.stdin.write(b"abcde\n")

# add file a with content `1234`
proc.stdin.write(b"M 644 inline testfile\n")
proc.stdin.write(b"data 4\n")
proc.stdin.write(b"1234\n")

proc.stdin.flush()
proc.stdin.close()
```

However, in the repo I'm seeing this:

```sh
$ git status
On branch master
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

    deleted:    testfile

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

    testfile
```

although git seems to know about testfile:

```
$ git show testfile
commit 85f343fa205665e7304dfbad1725b640a0d03b01 (HEAD -> master)
Author: Me <me@me.org>
Date:   Thu Jan 7 08:47:39 2021 +0100

    abcde

diff --git a/testfile b/testfile
new file mode 100644
index 0000000..274c005
--- /dev/null
+++ b/testfile
@@ -0,0 +1 @@
+1234
\ No newline at end of file
```

So, how can I tweak my `git fast-import` script to make git believe that the file `/tmp/git_fast_test/testfile` is exactly what is stored in it's index?

---

I found an [example shell script](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/contrib/fast-import/git-import.sh) in the original git source that should do almost exactly what I want to do and have the same issue with that script. So I believe this is the intended behavior of `git fast-import`...

Comment: (note : I don't know the internals of fast-import) Perhaps the issue is that the index is not up to date ? have you tried running `git update-index --refresh` or `git update-index --really-refresh` ?

Comment: I haven't, however `git reset HEAD` after the fast-import seems to clear everything up nicely and yields the desired result. I'm not sure what causes the delete stages, but at least that's a  workaround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[LeGEC's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65608431/git-fast-import-for-existing-files-in-the-repository/65613820#comment116000805_65608431) is in fact the right answer: fast-import bypasses the normal index-and-work-tree system, and when `git fast-import` exits, you have a bunch of *commits* but Git's index does not match any of them.  If you just created the repository, Git's index is completely empty, so the proposed next commit is that of an [empty tree](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9765453/1256452).  The comparison with the *current* commit will therefore say "to modify the current commit to make it match the proposed next commit, delete every file".

The fix is to run `git reset` (or `git restore` or `git read-tree`) to load Git's index.  You can optionally reset your work-tree at this time as well.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. That's what I get for using something advanced like `fast-import` without really knowing the internals of git. ;) `git reset --mixed HEAD` is what I'm using now.